# Turn a method call into a () => T function in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a method which looks the following:

```
def myMethod[T](klazz:Class[T]):Z
```

I want to create a Map of type `Int => () => Z` so that in my code, I can look on the map to generate only the `Z`s I need.

If I do the following, however:

```
Map( 0 -> myMethod(classOf[String]) _ , 1 -> myMethod(classOf[StringBuilder]))
```

how can I avoid writing `() => myMethod(classOf[String])`?

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply change `myMethod` so that it returns a function?

```
def myMethod( clazz: Class[_]): () => Z = {
  { () => /* put the body of the old myMethod here */ }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
Map( 0 -> myMethod(classOf[String]) , 1 -> myMethod(classOf[StringBuilder]))
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this is with a custom associator:

```
implicit class LazyMapArrow[K](val self: K) extends AnyVal {
  def ~>[V](other: => V): (K, () => V) = (self, () => other)
}
```